# Can I receive Push Notification to my mobile if I delete Authentication Key in Apple Developer Account

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I created an authentication Key in Apple Developer Account to implement push notification for my ios app. I used Firebase to send notification where I added .p8 file and provided Team ID and Key ID. now I am receiving notification successfully From Firebase, So in the future, if I delete this Authentication Key in Apple Developer Account will I receive notifications to mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase is using that key to authenticate with apple services when sending push notifications, removing the key from apple developer account will result in firebase not being able to authenticate and push notifications will stop working.